# How to differentiate 2 html classes with same name when testing them with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests

I am black box testing one web page as my school project. I am navigating trough the web site, checking functionalities and want to choose a job in job section and to apply to that job by filling the form.
Now, there are two job posts at the moment and they are under same name classes. I can open 1st of two jobs, but don't know how to navigate to 2nd one, since their names are the same, so my Selenium Web Driver test always opens the 1st one, and I want the second one.
I am working in Selenium Web Driver, c#.

```
<h4 class="job-section-title">Development / Belgrade</h4>
<div class="job-section">

<div class="job">
<h3>Software engineer</h3>
<div class="job-description">


<div class="job">
<h3 class="">Test engineer</h3>
<div class="job-description">
```

I tried to reach second job with this function: 
    //var selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Job")));

```
//selectElement.SelectByText("Test engineer");
```

Didn't work.
I hope that all the necessary information is provided.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update the question with the HTML for both the _two job posts_ including the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath to click on the element.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='Job']/h3[contains(.,'Test engineer')]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I figured out that there is no need to differentiate html classes in a way I wanted to. Selenium is a thing that also use css and xpath which do the job.
So i simply copied xpath (or css selector) and added it in my code like so:
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(xpath link))
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector link))

thank you all for your help :)